# How to prevent floating widgets in tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, floating

I have the following UI for my tkinter application. My problem is that the `OptionsMenu` with long text moves all other widgets to the right and eventually out of frame.

Solutions that I can think of:
1) Wrap text to next row.

2) A way that `StringVar` can truncate the selected text of the dropdown up until certain characters but does not change the original value (selected in dropdown) it stores.

3) Stop making them float and overlap over other widgets.

Here is the image of the erratic behavior.

[image]

Here is my code: for the Finding Category dropdown.

```
    if finding_names != []:
        finding_names.insert(0,'All')
        finding_type_select.set(finding_names[0])
        finding_type_dropdown = OptionMenu(tab3_project_reports,finding_type_select,*finding_names)
        finding_type_dropdown.configure(font='helvetica 12')
        finding_type_dropdown.grid(row=5, column=1,padx=10, pady=10,sticky=W+E+N+S)
        finding_type_dropdown.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

I have also tried to use the `grid_columnconfigure` but I did not really see any change.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot apply a column config directly to a widget. It needs to be apply to the widgets container. That said `weight=3` is probably a bad idea. This will tell the container to expand at 3 to 1 instead of 1 to 1. This would only make your problem worse I think.

Comment: You edited your code to show a different weight but you are still trying to do `grid_columnconfigure` on the widget instead of the container. If you really need a weight here (not sure if you do as you have not provided any usable code) then you would need to do `tab3_project_reports.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)` instead.

Comment: Yes i was just trying that! It actually works. You may put that as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see here that could be the problem (without seeing more code) is how you are using `grid_columnconfig()`. You can only apply a column/row config to a container. These would be the `root` window, a `Toplevel()` window or a `Frame`. You are currently using `grid_columnconfigure()` and that will work but note you can also just do `columnconfigure()` without the `grid_` portion. Same goes for rows.

Instead of this:

```
finding_type_dropdown.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Do this:

```
tab3_project_reports.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: Thanks this works great! Any other reference for future reading would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @technazi There is quite a bit to learn. Anything specific you are interested in?

Comment: I am aware about some basic tkinter layouts. I would like to know more about the configuration for grid column and grid row. That seems to give much more control over the widgets and their parents. The divide and conquer appraoch seems great. I tried to follow it to a great extent too.

Comment: @technazi the grid/column configure is very useful once you fully understand how it works. It allows for dynamic resizing of widgets. For example if you want a text box to resize with the window but do not want the side bar to resize this can be managed by weights. There is a good amount of documentation on Tkinter widgets [here.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tk.html)